# JMES to get only matching items

Tags: jmespath

I am trying to get the JMES query to give me only items which have a `Tag` with `Name` matching `Value` of `match`.

So far I have `GlobalNetworks[].[Tags[?Key==`Name `&& Value==`match`]]` but that gives me the non-matching one too.  I also only want the `GlobalNetworkId` of the matching item(s) with a projection

Can someone help please?

```
{
    "GlobalNetworks": [
        {
            "GlobalNetworkId": "abc",
            "GlobalNetworkArn": "arn:aws:networkmanager::xxx:global-network/global-network-1",
            "CreatedAt": "2023-07-11T23:13:58+12:00",
            "State": "AVAILABLE",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "match"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "GlobalNetworkId": "def",
            "GlobalNetworkArn": "arn:aws:networkmanager::xxx:global-network/global-network-2",
            "CreatedAt": "2023-07-11T23:13:58+12:00",
            "State": "AVAILABLE",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "nomatch"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "GlobalNetworkId": "ghi",
            "GlobalNetworkArn": "arn:aws:networkmanager::xxx:global-network/global-network-3",
            "CreatedAt": "2023-07-11T23:13:58+12:00",
            "State": "AVAILABLE",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "match"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below

```
GlobalNetworks[?Tags[?Key==`Name` && Value==`match`]]
```

gives (in YAML)

```yaml
- CreatedAt: '2023-07-11T23:13:58+12:00'
  GlobalNetworkArn: arn:aws:networkmanager::xxx:global-network/global-network-1
  GlobalNetworkId: abc
  State: AVAILABLE
  Tags:
  - Key: Name
    Value: match
- CreatedAt: '2023-07-11T23:13:58+12:00'
  GlobalNetworkArn: arn:aws:networkmanager::xxx:global-network/global-network-3
  GlobalNetworkId: ghi
  State: AVAILABLE
  Tags:
  - Key: Name
    Value: match
```